# Data Structure for saving Requirements for courses

Tags: java, data-structures

i'm struggling with an efficient way to store requirements for a course inside of a course.

e.g.:

- You can take part at course A when you passed B
- You can take part at course A too when you passed course C and D

I hoped to be able to use a tree structure so I can easily check if a Person passed all requirements but because of the multiple options to pass requirements it is not possible.

Do you know any technique or Data structure to solve this?

Comment: A tree is just a special form of a graph. I recommend looking at Guava's graph library: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained

Comment: You could go with a state machine (this is not a data structure).

Comment: It sounds like a `Course` could have a `Set<List<Course>> requirements`, where each List in the Set defines a group requirements.  if a `Person` has taken all of the `Course`s within **any** List then the requirement has been met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Course` object has a list of `Prerequisite` objects, only one of which needs to be *fulfilled*. A `Prerequisite` object has a list of required `Course` objects, all of which needs to be *passed* for the `Prerequisite` object to be *fulfilled*.

```
public class Course {
    private List<Prerequisite> prerequisites;

    public boolean canBeTakenBy(Student student) {
        return prerequisites.isEmpty() ||
               prerequisites.stream().anyMatch(p -> p.isFulfilledBy(student));
    }
}

public class Prerequisite {
    private List<Course> requiredCourses;

    public boolean isFulfilledBy(Student student) {
        return requiredCourses.stream().allMatch(student::hasPassed);
    }
}

public class Student {
    private Set<Course> passedCourses;

    public boolean hasPassed(Course course) {
        return passedCourses.contains(course);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can accomplish what you want, personally, I think the easiest is having an `ArrayList< ArrayList < Course > >`

So for example, if you want to add a possible requirement option, you could create an `ArrayList` with the courses and push it to the end of the requirements.

Later to check it, just run the combinations, complexity shouldn't be a problem, if you have for example 10 possible requirements with 10 courses each, worst case scenario it would be a 10x10 loop, 10² to the computer is the same as nothing at all.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: I came up with the same solution but I think there must be a smarter way to achieve the goal.